# T5 or BERT for sentence correction/generation task?

Tags: natural-language-processing, bert, text-generation

I have sentences with some grammatical errors , with no punctuations and digits written in words... something like below:

[image]

As you can observe, a proper noun , **winston** isnt highlighted with capital in Sample column. 'People' is spelled wrong and there are no punctuations in Sample column. The date in the first row isnt in right format. I have millions of rows like this and want to train a model to learn punctuations and corrections. Can a single BERT or T5 handle this task? or only option is to try 1 model for each task?
Thanks in advance

Comment: BERT might not be best option for this. I have tried both and T5 seems works better than BERT.